# How can I make each user only administrate his own content in the app?

Tags: react-native

For example, suppose I am making a restaurant app, which API should I use to let owners post their own restaurant and then manage it(title, available tables, foods etc.) from a dashboard? Can this be done with Sanity or Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

With firebase yeah - I had done something similar before.  You'll manage your users (restaurant owners) within Firebase.  You can have a "Role" column that would indicate permissions for that user on your app.

So for example, you may have an admin, manager and general user. Admins will have read/write access to everything whilst manager some of the content and general users read only.

**How to create users:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

**How to set 'custom properties'**, in your case - it can be the role: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties?platform=android

**Firestore** is a document based, non SQL database and free to a certain point: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

There many different ways this can be achieved, this would just be an example that comes to mind - and it would work for small scale projects.

If the app gets a lot of traffic and users, I'd switch to AWS.